# function is not defined when using $.mobile.changepage

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to execute `initialize()` function on page load, but by simple `<body onLoad="initialize()">` didn't work when page is called from other page by using `$.mobile.changePage`.
I've tried this, but it works fine only when i type the url of the page directly in the browser, not with redirecting.

FireBug: initialize is not defined

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page" data-theme="c" class="sss">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Skopje info guide</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>test</h1>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.sss').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
            popTable();
            initialize();
        });
    </script>
</div>
</body>
```

The function `initialize()` is in `<head>` part, and `popTable()` is in another .js file

Comment: What do you mean by "function initialize() is in part"?

Comment: well since you are using mobile, it could well be that a the live function loads before your "another .js file" therefore `popTable()` may fail to be called hence why you get function not defined.

Comment: are the javascript files in the main page or the transition too page? All javascript needs to be in the main page. So any javascript in the page being transitioned to needs to be in the main page and not itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like function initialize() is not in the calling page.  You either want the calling page to have the function definition, or include the function definition inside the data-role=page div